# Getting Duration using the new dateTime API

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

I want to get a [`java.time.Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) instance representing the duration of 3 years,
and i found 2 ways to do it (see code below).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Duration d1 = Duration.of(3, ChronoUnit.YEARS); //Runtime Exception
    Duration d2 = ChronoUnit.YEARS.getDuration().multipliedBy(3);

    System.out.println("d2="+d2.toDays()); //OUTPUT: d2=1095
}
```

The first way, `d1`, throws the following Exception at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unit must not have an estimated duration
    at java.time.Duration.plus(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.Duration.of(Unknown Source)
    at mod7.vehicalc.Test.main(Test.java:26)
```

The second way, `d2`, works as expected.

What is the reason for this difference?

Comment: The very concept of what you say is expected makes no sense. 3 years does not have a known number of days. It looks like the new interface is trying to prevent you from doing the mistake you called "works as expected"

Comment: You should probably be using a period instead.

Comment: @assylias I was thinking about that at first, but doesn't `Period` have a 'recurring' meaning?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A `Duration` is a time-based amount of time.

A `Period` is a date-based amount of time.

Given that years are clearly date-based and not time-based, you need to be using `Period`. (There is no "recurrance" aspect to `Period`).

```
Period p = Period.ofYears(3);
```

The estimated duration method on `ChronoUnit` is primarily intended for the purpose of sorting units, ie. being able to say that a year is generally longer than a month. It is not intended to be the basis of mathematical calculations or creating a larger `Duration`. In particular, if you use a `Period` then addition to a `LocalDate` or `ZonedDateTime` will result in the correct answer. If you use a `Duration` then you will probably get an unexpected/wrong answer.

Comment: `"Given that years are clearly date-based and not time-based"` that isn't as _clear_ as you think

Answer (score 8):

> What is the reason for this difference?

The javadoc for [`ChronoUnit#getDuration()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#getDuration--) states

> Gets the estimated duration of this unit in the ISO calendar system.

That is, [`YEARS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#YEARS) is a

> Unit that represents the concept of a year. For the ISO calendar
>   system, it is equal to 12 months. The estimated duration of a year is
>   365.2425 Days.

or 31556952 seconds. This is just an estimation.

[`Duration.of(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#of-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) expects a unit with an exact time value.

> This class models a quantity or amount of time in terms of seconds
>   and nanoseconds. It can be accessed using other duration-based units,
>   such as minutes and hours. In addition, the DAYS unit can be used and
>   is treated as exactly equal to 24 hours, thus ignoring daylight
>   savings effects.