# Is there a way to have a Java8 duration of one year that accounts for leap years?

Tags: java, java-8, duration

I need the number of days in a year and I wanted to use Java8's new time api.

However, I can't do `Duration.ofDays(365)` because it doesn't account for leap years.  And `Duration.of(1, ChronoUnit.YEARS)` doesn't fly because of `java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unit must not have an estimated duration`

I looked into Period, but it doesn't appear useful for going from years to days.

I feel like I'm missing something here?  I could write something to add a day if the year is a leap year, but it seems like I should be able to handle this out of the box.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Duration using the new dateTime API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454129/getting-duration-using-the-new-datetime-api)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As per the response in [Getting Duration using the new dateTime API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454129/getting-duration-using-the-new-datetime-api) you should be using

```
Period p = Period.ofYears(1);
```

It's important to understand the difference between `Duration` (exact number of nanoseconds < 1 day) and `Period` (variable > 1 day).

`Duration` won't account for leap days, daylight savings time or leap seconds, for example, and is intended for durations of less than a day, at most a few days.

So you should use `Period` instead.

Because different years have different number of days, if you want to find the number of days in a year, you need to specify which year you're talking about.

If you want the number of days in a specific year, you can use

```
Year.of(year).length()
```

If you want the date one year from now, you can use

```
LocalDate.now().plusYears(1)
```

or

```
LocalDate.now().plus(Period.ofYears(1))
```

If you need the number of days between two dates, you can use

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end)
```

So to find the number of days to the date a year from now, you can use

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(today, today.plusYears(1));
```

If you want to see whether a membership of one year is still valid, you can use

```
Period membershipLength = Period.ofYears(1);
LocalDate membershipStart = ...;
LocalDate membershipEnd = membershipStart.plus(membershipLength);

LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
boolean memberShipEnded = today.isAfter(membershipEnd);
boolean membershipValid = !membershipEnded;
```

Comment: Since one year can have a variable number of days, this is not possible. Please tell, what is the next calculation that you will be using the number of days for, and maybe we can find another way?

Comment: There is no next calculation.  Think of it like the length of a membership or subscription.  If you start a membership today that lasts for a year, what day will the membership end? (and I wanted to use java8 date/time)

Comment: @user2272115: You need to specify the year that you're interested in, since different years have different length. So for "today", that is `Year.now().length()`. If you want the date that the membership ends, that is `LocalDate.now().plusYears(1)`.

Comment: @user2272115: So you don't actually need the number of days in a year, it sounds like you need `LocalDate.now().isBefore(membershipStart.plusYears(1))`.
The next calculation is "when does the membership end"?

Comment: @ Christoffer Hammarstrom ended up using `Duration.ofDays(DAYS.between(startDate, startDate.plusYears(1)))`

Comment: @user2272115: Cool, just make sure that you understand the difference between `Duration` (exact number of nanoseconds) and `Period` (variable). Duration won't account for daylight savings time or leap seconds, for example. So it's really better if you're able to use LocalDates and Periods instead.

Comment: To be clear, in this case `Period` is the right choice over `Duration`.

Answer (score 9):

It seems clear you do not want a duration (= between two dates), but the year length of a specific date.

```
LocalDate dateLeap = LocalDate.of(2004, Month.MARCH, 1);
System.out.println("leap year of " + dateLeap
    + " has days: " + dateLeap.lengthOfYear());
```

> leap year of 2004-03-01 has days: 366

Java 8 Date & Time is astonishing complete.

---

If you mean, in January 5th 2004 to January 5th 2005 = **366** and March 2nd 2004 to March 2rd 2005 = **365**:

```
int lengthOfYear(LocalDate date) {
    return date.getMonthValue() <= 2
        ? date.lengthOfYear()               // Count Feb in this year
        : date.plusYears(1).lengthOfYear(); // Count Feb in next year
}
```

Explanation: basically the length is 365. But if date is >= March, the February in the next year is counted, otherwise this year's February.

Mind that `plusYears(1)` will not change DAY or MONTH.

Also neither leap second nor hour/minuts on February, 29th are considered.

Comment: Also you can do `Year.of(2004).length()`.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström the simplest solution to keep in mind.

Comment: I do want a duration.  The duration between between today and 1 year from today, and I want that duration in number of days.  There's a few ways I can determine which years have 366 days.

Comment: @JoopEggen: Regarding your extension, it's better to use `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date, date.plusYears(1))`. That way you don't need to manually test the month.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström That might be the **best** answer to the question.